# HTML plotting data via Plotly in Javascript not showing any data

Tags: javascript, html, plot, plotly

I am trying to plot some data on an HTML site via JS from my own server, yet I don't manage to get any visual data.

The plotting tool I'm using is Plotly.

This is my JS code, trying to plot the data:

```
TESTER = document.getElementById('graphDiv');
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var preise=[]
var allePreise={}
var daten=[]
var alleDaten={}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "[HTTP LINK]", true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

 
    console.log(data)
    for (x in data) {
      preise=[]
      daten=[]
        for(y in data[x]){

        preise.push((data[x][y].price))
        daten.push((data[x][y].date))
        }
        allePreise[x]=preise
        alleDaten[x]=daten

  }
    console.log(allePreise["CS20 Case"])
    console.log(alleDaten["CS20 Case"])

  }
  var counter=0
for (i in allePreise){
  counter=counter+1
var trace1 = {
  x: alleDaten[i],
  y: allePreise[i],
  mode: 'lines'
}
}
  
Plotly.plot( TESTER, [{
    trace1
    //type: 'bar',
    //mode: 'lines+markers',
     }], { 
    margin: { t: 0 } 
   },
   {scrollZoom: true}
);
  };
```

This is a code snippet of the data after it's converted into the two arrays:

```
[5.492,3.006,1.618,1.373,1.014,0.665]
["Oct 18 2019 01: +0","Oct 19 2019 01: +0","Oct 20 2019 01: +0"]
```

Is there something wrong with my code or with my data? I tried for more than an hour now.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your plot syntax.

First it should be `Plotly.newPlot` instead of `Plotly.plot`. There doesn't exist a `Plotly.plot` function (At least not in the version I tested: 2.3.1 (current latest version). The same applies for other versions, but I haven't tested them all).

Also the way you're passing the parameters to the plot function is not correct. It should be of the form:

```
Plotly.newPlot(graphDiv, data, layout, config)
```

> graphDiv DOM node or string id of a DOM node
> data array of objects (defaults to [])
> layout object (defaults to {})
> config object (defaults to {})

https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlynewplot

So a reproducible example could look like this:

```
const x = ["Oct 18 2019 01: +0", "Oct 19 2019 01: +0", "Oct 20 2019 01: +0"];
const y = [5.492, 3.006, 1.618, 1.373, 1.014, 0.665];
const trace1 = {
  x: x,
  y: y,
  mode: "lines",
};

Plotly.newPlot(
  "graphDiv",
  [trace1],
  { margin: { t: 0 } },
  { scrollZoom: true }
);
```